# How do I create a new proxy in Windows?

Tags: proxy

I am trying to setup BrowserMobProxy and the instructions in the README found here: https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy say to run the batch file, which I have and then to do the following to create a new proxy, using the following command:

```
[~]$ curl -X POST http://localhost:9090/proxy
{"port":9091}
```

How do I do this in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions here: http://rdekleijn.nl/functional-testing-over-a-proxy-with-browsermob-proxy/

The only thing that I would change is that when I wanted to get the curl command to work that I had to point it to c:\Program Files\cURL\bin and then run the curl command. It did work though.